# Disappearing comments on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, comments

So I've recently been seeing a lot of comments on questions and answers alike, being removed with no explanation as to **why** or **what** the purpose is for removing the comment.

I mean, wasn't the comments supposed be a place for discussion? And I obviously mean discussions that actually try to understand the question before giving an answer, or discussions that relate to a given answer. And now, as I read some questions/answers, it looks as if one single person is talking to/replying to themselves throughout the comment section. Or I see a single comment that is talking about something that looks quite out of place in relation to the question or answer.

If the comment section has changed to become something else, then an explanation would be nice, *as well* as the new solution for asking for clarification from questioners/answerers alike.

<sub>If this is a bot doing this, then please kindly delete that code,
 because it's malfunctioning.</sub>

---

To reiterate, my question is, **why** and **what** is the purpose or criteria for deleting comments, and **what** is the **solution** to leaving comments on questions?

Comment: Comments are either deleted by the author, by flags (given enough flags accumulating on them) or by a moderator (almost always in response to still-active flags). Apart from “possible duplicate” comments there is no automated comment deletion.

Comment: Comments are generally ephemeral in nature. Temporary, always subject to deletion.

Comment: Their temporary nature is highlighted right at the start of the relevant help page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: *it looks as if one single person is talking to/replying to themselves throughout the comment section. Or I see a single comment that is talking about something that looks quite out of place in relation to the question or answer.* - You can flag those as no longer needed.

Comment: If I address something in a comment and it gets subsequently fixed, that comment is no longer needed – and it even may be counterproductive to keep it.

Comment: Comments are not deleted, only hidden, so if you like you can point to a specific question, and a moderator here will tell you why those comments were hidden.

Answer (score 10):

Commments are removed (actually hidden) for a couple of reasons:

1. The author of the comment clicked the delete button.
2. A moderator has intervened for some reason and removed comments.  This typically happens when a discussion "has gotten out of hand", but it can also happen when someone flags comments as no longer relevant.
3. Apparently comments flagged as rude / abusive can be removed automatically (@Robert Longson).

When you see a half of a conversation in a comment stream, it is a clear sign that the other person has deleted their comments.  People can do that for any reason.

What can you do about it?

- There is nothing you can do to stop people deleting their own comments.  It happens.  People are people.
- I'm not aware if there is an "official" way to request comments be restored.  Flagging a question or answer for moderator attention would be one way, but it might actually have the opposite effect to what you requested.  (The moderator may just clean up the remaining comments.)
- If you find the one-sided comments distracting, you can flag them to be removed by a moderator.  Flag them as redundant rather than rude.

Comment: The third reason is that the comment included some kind of rude word from the secret list of rude words, in which case anyone who can flag can delete the comment.

Comment: 6 r/a flags are needed to auto-nuke a comment (less if it contains specific swear words). On top of that if there are comments that contain certain trigger words (like *please accept my answer* or *Thanks, that worked!*) a single comment flag (of any type) is enough to have the comment deleted by the system.